# DynamoDB to Elasticsearch with AWS SDK v2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I came across [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885140/push-data-from-dynamo-db-to-elasticsearch-using-java), showing how to push data from DynamoDB to Elasticsearch for full-text search indexing.  Our application, however, is not making use of Lambdas.  Instead, we're using Apache Camel to capture DynamoDB Streams events and want to push the records to Elasticsearch from there.

Since we are using AWS SDK v2, we're not capturing a `DynamodbEvent` class or corresponding `DynamodbStreamRecord` record class containing the DynamoDB record.  Instead, we are receiving a `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.Record` object.  Given that, how can we serialize and subsequently index this data in Elasticsearch?  In the other question referenced, the record is converted to a JSON string and then sent over to Elasticsearch.  Is there a way to do this with the v2 `Record` class?  The `ItemUtils` class mentioned in the answer no longer exists, so I was unaware of another way to serialize it.

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the example you provided, you can try something like the following:

```java
public void processRecord(Record record, String index, String type, RestHighLevelClient esClient) throws Exception {
  // Get operation
  final OperationType operationType = record.eventName();
  // Obtain a reference to actual DynamoDB stream record
  final StreamRecord streamRecord = record.dynamodb();
  // Get ID. Assume single numeric attribute as partition key
  final Map<String,AttributeValue> keys = streamRecord.keys();
  final String recordId = keys.get("ID").n();

  switch (operationType) {
    case INSERT:
      if (!streamRecord.hasNewImage()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No new image when inserting");
      }
      Map<String,AttributeValue> newImage = streamRecord.newImage();
      // Where toJson is defined here https://github.com/aaronanderson/aws-java-sdk-v2-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/DynamoDBUtil.java
      // and included below
      JsonObject jsonObject = toJson(newImage);
      IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index, type, recordId);
      indexRequest.source(jsonObject.toString(), XContentType.JSON);
      IndexResponse indexResponse = esClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
      System.out.println("New content successfully indexed: " + indexResponse);
      break;
    case MODIFY:
      if (!streamRecord.hasNewImage()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No new image when updating");
      }
      Map<String,AttributeValue> newImage = streamRecord.newImage();
      JsonObject jsonObject = toJson(newImage);
      UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, type, recordId);
      request.doc(jsonObject.toString(), XContentType.JSON);
      UpdateResponse updateResponse = esClient.update(updateRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
      System.out.println("Content successfully updated: " + updateResponse);
      break;
    case REMOVE:
      DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(index, type, recordId);
      DeleteResponse deleteResponse = esClient.delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
      System.out.println("Successfully removed: " + deleteResponse);
      break;
    default:
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation type " + opetationType + " not supportd");  
  }
}
```

The `toJson` method is defined is this class: https://github.com/aaronanderson/aws-java-sdk-v2-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/DynamoDBUtil.java

The source code is reproduced here:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonNumber;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonString;
import javax.json.JsonStructure;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

/** This is a utility for converting DynamoDB AttributeValues to and from Java JSON-P objects */
public class DynamoDBUtil {

    public static void addList(String key, JsonObjectBuilder objectBuilder, List<JsonObject> items) {
        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
            items.forEach(i -> builder.add(i));
            objectBuilder.add(key, builder.build());
        }

    }

    public static JsonArray toJson(List<AttributeValue> attributeValues) {
        if (attributeValues == null) {
            return null;
        }
        JsonArrayBuilder valueBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (AttributeValue a : attributeValues) {
            add(toJson(a), valueBuilder);
        }
        return valueBuilder.build();
    }

    public static JsonObject toJson(Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues) {
        if (attributeValues == null) {
            return null;
        }
        JsonObjectBuilder valueBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, AttributeValue> a : attributeValues.entrySet()) {
            add(a.getKey(), toJson(a.getValue()), valueBuilder);
        }
        return valueBuilder.build();
    }

    public static void add(String key, Object value, JsonObjectBuilder object) {
        if (value instanceof JsonValue) {
            object.add(key, (JsonValue) value);
            // with json-p 1.0 can't create JsonString or JsonNumber so simply setting JsonValue not an option.
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            object.add(key, (String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            object.add(key, (BigDecimal) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            object.add(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value == null || value.equals(JsonValue.NULL)) {
            object.addNull(key);
        }

    }

    public static void add(Object value, JsonArrayBuilder array) {
        if (value instanceof JsonValue) {
            array.add((JsonValue) value);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            array.add((String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            array.add((BigDecimal) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            array.add((Boolean) value);
        } else if (value.equals(JsonValue.NULL)) {
            array.addNull();
        }

    }

    public static Object toJson(AttributeValue attributeValue) {
        // with json-p 1.1 Json.createValue() can be used.

        if (attributeValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (attributeValue.s() != null) {
            return attributeValue.s();
        }
        if (attributeValue.n() != null) {
            return new BigDecimal(attributeValue.n());
        }
        if (attributeValue.bool() != null) {
            // return attributeValue.bool() ? JsonValue.TRUE : JsonValue.FALSE;
            return attributeValue.bool();
        }

        if (attributeValue.b() != null) {
            // return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(attributeValue.b().array());
            return null;
        }

        if (attributeValue.nul() != null && attributeValue.nul()) {
            return JsonValue.NULL;
        }

        if (!attributeValue.m().isEmpty()) {
            return toJson(attributeValue.m());
        }
        if (!attributeValue.l().isEmpty()) {
            return toJson(attributeValue.l());
        }

        if (!attributeValue.ss().isEmpty()) {
            return attributeValue.ss();
        }

        if (!attributeValue.ns().isEmpty()) {
            return attributeValue.ns();
        }

        if (!attributeValue.bs().isEmpty()) {
            //return attributeValue.bs();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Map<String, AttributeValue> toAttribute(JsonObject jsonObject) {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> attribute = new HashMap<>();
        jsonObject.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            attribute.put(e.getKey(), toAttribute(e.getValue()));
        });
        return attribute;
    }

    public static List<AttributeValue> toAttribute(JsonArray jsonArray) {
        List<AttributeValue> attributes = new LinkedList<>();
        jsonArray.forEach(e -> {
            attributes.add(toAttribute(e));
        });
        return attributes;
    }

    public static AttributeValue toAttribute(JsonValue jsonValue) {
        if (jsonValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        switch (jsonValue.getValueType()) {
        case STRING:
            return AttributeValue.builder().s(((JsonString) jsonValue).getString()).build();
        case OBJECT:
            return AttributeValue.builder().m(toAttribute((JsonObject) jsonValue)).build();
        case ARRAY:
            return AttributeValue.builder().l(toAttribute((JsonArray) jsonValue)).build();
        case NUMBER:
            return AttributeValue.builder().n(((JsonNumber) jsonValue).toString()).build();
        case TRUE:
            return AttributeValue.builder().bool(true).build();
        case FALSE:
            return AttributeValue.builder().bool(false).build();
        case NULL:
            return AttributeValue.builder().nul(true).build();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static AttributeValue compress(Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues) throws IOException {
        return compress(toJson(attributeValues));
    }

    public static AttributeValue compress(List<AttributeValue> attributeValues) throws IOException {
        return compress(toJson(attributeValues));
    }

    public static AttributeValue compress(JsonStructure jsonStructure) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Json.createWriter(outputStream).write(jsonStructure);
        outputStream.close();
        byte[] jsonBinary = outputStream.toByteArray();

        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(jsonBinary);
        deflater.finish();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        jsonBinary = outputStream.toByteArray();

        return AttributeValue.builder().b(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(jsonBinary)).build();
    }

    public static JsonStructure decompress(AttributeValue attributeValue) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        byte[] jsonBinary = attributeValue.b().asByteArray();
        inflater.setInput(jsonBinary);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(jsonBinary.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(output);
        return Json.createReader(bis).read();
    }

}
```

This class is an updated version of the originally introduced in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronanderson/ef6d319220d0ff938fa3c1013c4e80de).

This post also provide a [link](https://gist.github.com/nickman/991dea808b6f43e7346d6d570f3c9ffe) to a Jackson's `AtributeValue` serializer if your prefer to use that library for JSON serialization.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  The DynamoDbUtil piece was really the one I was missing.  Don’t know how I didn’t know about that!

Comment: Great @Shadowman!! I agree with you, all credit goes to the class ```DynamoDbUtil```. I am glad to hear the answer was helpful!!